# Implement stack of function pointers in Delphi

Tags: delphi, callback, function-pointers, delphi-7

We have declared a type which can be used as a progress callback (such as loading every 10,000 lines from a gigantic log file):

```
// Declared in some base unit
TProcedureCallback = procedure() of object;

// Declared in the class that loads the events
procedure ReadEvents(callback: TProcedureCallback);

// Implementation of above method
procedure TEvents.ReadEvents(callback: TProcedureCallback);
var
    nEvents: Integer;
begin
    nEvents := 0;

    // Read some events...
    Inc(nEvents);
    // ...and repeat until end of log file

    // Every 10,000 events, let the caller know (so they update
    // something like a progress bar)
    if ((nEvents mod 10000) = 0) then
        callback();
end;

// And the caller uses it like this
public
    procedure EventsLoadCallBack();

// Implementation of callback
procedure TfrmLoadEvents.EventsLoadCallBack();
begin
    // Update some GUI control...
end;

// And the events are loaded like this
events.ReadEvents(EventsLoadCallBack);
```

This all works very well...but I'd like to extend this to the TObjectStack container so that we can implement an automatic log off feature. The idea is that as each form is created, it registers a callback (ie. pushes it onto some system-wide stack). And when the form is destroyed, it pops the callback off the stack. If the auto log off occurs, you just unwind the stack and return the user to the main form and then do the rest of work associated with an automatic log off.

But, I cannot get it working...when I try and push a TProcedureCallback  object onto the stack I get compiler errors:

```
// Using generic containers unit from Delphi 7
uses
  Contnrs;

// Declare stack
stackAutoLogOff: TObjectStack;

// Initialise stack
stackAutoLogOff := TObjectStack.Create();

// Attempt to use stack
stackAutoLogOff.Push(callback);
stackAutoLogOff.Push(TObject(callback));

// Clean up...
stackstackAutoLogOff.Free();
```

The 1st returns `Incompatible types` and the 2nd `Invalid typecast`. What is the correct way to implement a stack of function pointers?

Comment: OK, so your problem is that the stack class you have accepts pointers. But you have a double pointer type. So you can't use it. Instead you can implement a simple enough stack class for your double pointer types that uses a dynamic array as the underlying storage. With generics this is trivial, using the built in classes. Without that it's a lot of annoying boilerplate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `TObjectStack` expects to contain objects of type `TObject` and your callback is a [`TMethod`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TMethod) type, which is a record containing two pointers.

If you are using a modern version of Delphi a simple solution is to use generics.  For example:

```
 TObjectProc = procedure of object;
 TMyCallbackStack = TStack<TObjectProc>;
```

Without generics, you would need to build your own stack class to manage storage of the callbacks. This is a reasonably simple class to build and, at its most basic, might look something like this :

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;
type
  TMyClass = class
    procedure foo;
  end;

  TObjProc = procedure of object;
  TObjProcStack = class(TObject)
    private
      FList: array of TObjProc;
    public
      function Count: Integer;
      procedure Push(AItem: TObjProc);
      function Pop: TObjProc; inline;
      function Peek: TObjProc; inline;
  end;


function TObjProcStack.Peek: TObjProc;
begin
  Result := FList[Length(FList)-1];
end;

function TObjProcStack.Pop: TObjProc;
begin
  Result := Peek();
  SetLength(FList, Length(FList) - 1);
end;

procedure TObjProcStack.Push(AItem: TObjProc);
begin
  SetLength(FList, Length(FList) + 1);
  FList[Length(FList)-1] := AItem;
end;

function TObjProcStack.Count: Integer;
begin
  Result := Length(FList);
end;


{TMyClass}
procedure TMyClass.Foo;
begin
  WriteLn('foo');
end;

var
  LMyClass : TMyClass;
  LStack : TObjProcStack;
begin
  LStack := TObjProcStack.Create;
  LMyClass := TMyClass.Create;
  try
    LStack.Push(LMyClass.foo);
    LStack.Pop;   {executes TMyClass.Foo - outputs 'foo' to console}
  finally
    LStack.Free;
    LMyClass.Free;
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: Nice answer with added detail about the improvements the developer can look forward since Delphi 7.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the callback in an object and then use the standard Stack options. By wrapping *that* in your own class, you have a complete solution, like this:

```
unit UnitCallbackStack;

interface

uses
  Contnrs;

type
  TProcedureCallback = procedure() of object;


type
  TMyCallbackObject = class    // wrapper for callback
  private
    FCallBack : TProcedureCallback;
  protected
  public
    constructor Create( ACallback : TProcedureCallback ); reintroduce;
    property CallBack : TProcedureCallback
             read FCallBack;
  end;

type
  TCallBackStack = class( TObjectStack)
  private
  public
    function Push(ACallback: TProcedureCallback): TProcedureCallback; reintroduce;
    function Pop: TProcedureCallback; reintroduce;
    function Peek: TProcedureCallback; reintroduce;

  end;

implementation

{ TCallBackStack }

function TCallBackStack.Peek: TProcedureCallback;
var
  iObject : TMyCallbackObject;
begin
  iObject := inherited Peek as TMyCallbackObject;
  if assigned( iObject ) then
  begin
    Result := iObject.CallBack; // no delete here as reference not removed
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := nil;
  end;
end;

function TCallBackStack.Pop: TProcedureCallback;
var
  iObject : TMyCallbackObject;
begin
  iObject := inherited Pop as TMyCallbackObject;
  if assigned( iObject ) then
  begin
    Result := iObject.CallBack;
    iObject.Free; // popped, so no longer needed
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := nil;
  end;
end;

function TCallBackStack.Push(ACallback: TProcedureCallback): TProcedureCallback;
begin
  inherited Push( TMyCallbackObject.Create( ACallBack ));
end;


{ TMyCallbackObject }

constructor TMyCallbackObject.Create(ACallback: TProcedureCallback);
begin
  inherited Create;
  fCallBack := ACallBack;
end;

end.
```

You can then use TCallBackStack the way you are trying to use TStack.

Comment: Have implemented your suggested schema and it works nicely. There are a few little wrinkles to work out in the context of an automatic log off feature such as ensuring that when the child form closes via user action (ie. NOT an auto log off event), it de-registers from the system stack but these are implementation details specific to my problem.